# Can not connect to node app running in Docker container from browser

Tags: node.js, docker, centos, vps, bluehost

I am running a nodejs application in a Docker container. The application is hosted on a bluehost centOS VPS to which I connect using SSH. I use the following command to run the app in the container: `sudo docker run -p 80:8080 -d skepticalbonobo/dandakou-nodeapp`. Then I check that the container is running using `sudo docker ps` and sure enough it is. But when I try to access the app from Chrome using the domain name or IP address I get: "This site can’t be reached". I have noticed however that in the output of sudo docker ps, under COMMAND I get `docker-entrypoint...` as opposed to `node app.js` and I do not know how to fix it.You can pull the container using `docker pull skepticalbonobo/dandakou-nodeapp`. Here is the content of my Dockerfile:

```
RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app/node_modules && chown -R node:node /home/node/app

WORKDIR /home/node/app

COPY package*.json ./

USER node

RUN npm install

COPY . .

USER root

RUN chown -R node:node . .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "node", "app.js" ]
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you able to connect from your host machine to your app running (in docker) at localhost, for e.g. with curl?

Comment: Can you include the `FROM` line in your Dockerfile, and also any output the container prints when it starts up?  If it says something like "listening on 127.0.0.1:8080" it will be unreachable from outside the container, and you need to change that bind address to 0.0.0.0.

Comment: Can you try and run the docker container locally ? If it runs correctly then it's a issue with the way you've set access outside of Bluehost

Comment: Check if the firewall settings bluehost, you have allowed external access to port 80.

Answer (score 1):

The default for Nodejs app is 3000.
Run following command and check on which port node app is running

```
sudo docker run -ti skepticalbonobo/dandakou-nodeapp /bin/sh
```

Expose in Dockerfile is just for documentation purpose.